# The best algorithm to get index with specific range at pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, algorithm

I need to implement whether the driver was overspeeding while driving.
GPS information is uploaded every second from the GPS device installed in the vehicle driven by the driver like below.

```
[(37.165224, 127.2354123), ... ,(37.123456, 127.123456)]
```

Also, There is the speed limit information for each roal in grid format like below.

```
(MinX, MaxX, MinY, MaxY, Speed Limit)
[37.123456, 37.123458, 127.123456, 127.123458, 80]
[37.123457, 37.123458, 127.123457, 127.123459, 70]
...
```

This grid information has overlapping parts, which is information caused by overpasses.

Accordingly, if the driver is included in a plurality of grid information, it was decided to select the maximum speed of the corresponding speed limits as the speed limit.

For example, in the above information, if the driver is included in `(37.123457, 127.123457)`, the speed limit is `80` or `70` according to the grid information, and the speed limit is determined to be `80` based on the maximum limit speed rule.

I decided to implement this as a daily batch, and implemented it using pandas dataframe as follows.

```py
with open("/path/file.pickle", "rb") as f:
  matsers:list = pickle.load(f)

def func_max_spd_iterrow(lon, lat, master):
  limit_spd = -1
  if ((lat >= 33.0) & (lat <= 39.0)):
    locs = master.loc[(master['MINY']<=lat)&(master['MAXY']>lat)&(master['MINX']<=lon)&(master['MAXX']>lon)]
  
  if(locs.size != 0):
    spd = locs['LIMIT_SPD'].max()
  return spd
```

As shown above, grid information is loaded using pickle, and the length of the data is about 10 million.
So, just analyzing one driver's 2,000 seconds of driving takes about 12 seconds

Therefore, I have a problem to analyze 3,000 trip information because it is extremely time consuming.

**Is there a suitable algorithm to solve this problem or pandas dataframe method that can speed up indexing?**

Comment: You should look at R-Tree and [GeoPandas Spatial Index](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/sindex.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#Convert your grid information into GeoDataFrame:
import geopandas as gpd

# Create a GeoDataFrame from your grid information
gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(grid_info, 
                       columns=['Speed Limit'], 
                       geometry=gpd.GeoSeries([Polygon([(minX, minY), (maxX, minY), (maxX, maxY), (minX, maxY)]) 
                                               for minX, maxX, minY, maxY, _ in grid_info]))
```

then,

```
#Create a spatial index for the GeoDataFrame:
gdf.sindex
```

then,

```
#Iterate through your GPS points and perform spatial queries:
from shapely.geometry import Point

def find_speed_limit(lon, lat):
    point = Point(lon, lat)
    possible_matches_index = list(gdf.sindex.intersection(point.bounds))
    possible_matches = gdf.iloc[possible_matches_index]

    for idx, row in possible_matches.iterrows():
        if point.within(row['geometry']):
            return row['Speed Limit']

    return -1  # No matching grid cell found
```

**Example usage:**

```
speed_limit = find_speed_limit(37.165224, 127.2354123)
print(speed_limit)
```