# The fastest way of pyspark and geodataframe to check if a point is contained in a polygon

Tags: python, pyspark, geopandas

A CSV file read through pyspark contains tens of thousands of GPS information (lat, lon) and a feather file read through geodataframe contains millions of polygon information.

In the previous question ([The best algorithm to get index with specific range at pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77109105/the-best-algorithm-to-get-index-with-specific-range-at-pandas-dataframe)),  I succeeded in creating a geodataframe.

However, it was confirmed that a large amount of calculation time was consumed when using geodataframe with data read from pyspark.

First, data was loaded through pyspark in the following.

```
data = spark.read.option("header", True).csv("path/file.csv")
```

The data contains second-by-second GPS information about the vehicle as follows:

| time | Vehicle.Location.Latitude | Vehicle.Location.Longitude |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:00 | 37.123456 | 123.123456 |
| 2023-01-01 00:00:01 | 37.123457 | 123.123457 |

Second, the previously created geodataframe data was loaded as follows

```
gdf = gpd.read_feather("/path/file.feather")
```

The geodataframe contains geometry information as follow:

| id | MAX_SPD | geometry |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 60 | POLYGON ((126.27306 33.19865, 126.27379 33.198... |
| 1 | 60 | POLYGON ((126.27222 33.19865, 126.27306 33.198... |

Next, I created a user-defined function within pyspark.

The purpose is to find out the MAX_SPD value of the polygon that contains given GPS information. If it is included in multiple polygons, max(MAX_SPD) is retrieved.

```
def find_intersection(longitude, latitude):
    if type(longitude) != float or type(latitude) != float:
        return -1
    mgdf = gdf['geometry'].contains(Point(longitude, latitude))
    max_spd = gdf.loc[mgdf, 'MAX_SPD'].max()
    if math.isnan(max_spd):
        max_spd = -1
    return max_spd

find_intersection_udf = udf(find_intersection, IntegerType())
data = data.withColumn("max_spd", find_intersection_udf(col("`Vehicle.Location.Longitude`"), col("`Vehicle.Location.Latitude`")))
data.select("`max_spd`").show()
```

However, Using user-defined function seems to be time consuming.
Are there any other good ideas to redue time consumption?

Comment: Let me know if my answer helps you out in anyway. And the kind of speedups you receive. Would be good to know how well this library scales?

Comment: @user238607 Thank you for your answer. I appreciate it. However, I have tried to reflect it in my current local env, but problem related to JAR files at Apache-Sedona continues to occur. Since it seems like it won't be possible quickly, I plan to work on it again in AWS Glue. This is a different type of problem from the question currently asked, so I will solve it later and let you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use Apache Sedona for your geospatial analysis.

https://sedona.apache.org/latest-snapshot/tutorial/sql/

I adapted this notebook to give you an example of how to do this.
All you have to do is readin your Points CSV into point_rdd and polygon data in feather file format into Geopandas dataframe and then convert into polygon_rdd. Do a join query and get results. The results will have your attributes like `MAX_SPD` and then you do a aggregate query to retrieve the max value i.e. `max(MAX_SPD)` .

Notebook :

https://github.com/apache/sedona/blob/master/binder/ApacheSedonaCore.ipynb

Data used in the following script can be found at this location :

https://github.com/apache/sedona/tree/master/binder/data

Requirements :

`pip install apache-sedona`

`pip install geopandas`

`pip install folium`

Python script :

```
import sys

import folium
from pyspark import StorageLevel
import geopandas as gpd
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType
from pyspark.sql.types import StructField
from sedona.spark import *


config = SedonaContext.builder() .\
    config('spark.jars.packages',
           'org.apache.sedona:sedona-spark-shaded-3.0_2.12:1.4.1,'
           'org.datasyslab:geotools-wrapper:1.4.0-28.2'). \
    config("spark.serializer", KryoSerializer.getName). \
    config("spark.kryo.registrator", SedonaKryoRegistrator.getName). \
    getOrCreate()

sedona = SedonaContext.create(config)

sc = sedona.sparkContext

point_rdd = PointRDD(sc, "../sedona_data/arealm-small.csv", 1, FileDataSplitter.CSV, True, 10, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY, "epsg:4326", "epsg:4326")

## Getting approximate total count
count_approx = point_rdd.approximateTotalCount
print("approximate count", count_approx)

# To run analyze please use function analyze
print("analyse is here", point_rdd.analyze())

# collect to Python list
points_List = point_rdd.rawSpatialRDD.collect()[:5]

print("Printng point list")
print(points_List)

point_rdd_to_geo = point_rdd.rawSpatialRDD.map(lambda x: [x.geom, *x.getUserData().split("\t")])

point_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(
    point_rdd_to_geo.collect(), columns=["geom", "attr1", "attr2", "attr3"], geometry="geom"
)

print("GeoPandas Dataframe")
print(point_gdf[:5])


spatial_df = Adapter.\
    toDf(point_rdd, ["attr1", "attr2", "attr3"], sedona).\
    createOrReplaceTempView("spatial_df")

spatial_gdf = sedona.sql("Select attr1, attr2, attr3, geometry as geom from spatial_df")

spatial_gdf.show(5, False)


## Apache Sedona spatial partitioning method can
# significantly speed up the join query.
# Three spatial partitioning methods are available:
# KDB-Tree, Quad-Tree and R-Tree.
# Two SpatialRDD must be partitioned by the same way.


## Very Important : Choose the Same Spatial Paritioning Everywhere. in this case GridType.KDBTREE
done_value = point_rdd.spatialPartitioning(GridType.KDBTREE)
print("spatial partitioniing done value = ", done_value)

polygon_rdd = PolygonRDD(sc, "../sedona_data/primaryroads-polygon.csv", FileDataSplitter.CSV, True, 11, StorageLevel.MEMORY_ONLY, "epsg:4326", "epsg:4326")
print(polygon_rdd.analyze())
polygon_rdd.spatialPartitioning(point_rdd.getPartitioner())  ### This retrieves the same paritioner i.e. GridType.KDBTREE

# building an index
point_rdd.buildIndex(IndexType.RTREE, True)
polygon_rdd.buildIndex(IndexType.RTREE, True)

# Perform Spatial Join Query
result = JoinQuery.SpatialJoinQueryFlat(point_rdd, polygon_rdd, True, False)

print("Result of the Join Query")
print(result.take(2))


schema = StructType(
    [
        StructField("geom_left", GeometryType(), False),
        StructField("geom_right", GeometryType(), False)
    ]
)

# Set verifySchema to False
spatial_join_result = result.map(lambda x: [x[0].geom, x[1].geom])
sedona_df = sedona.createDataFrame(spatial_join_result, schema, verifySchema=False)

print("Schema of Sedona Dataframe")
print(sedona_df.printSchema())

print("Values here")
sedona_df.show(n=10, truncate=False)


gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(sedona_df.rdd.collect(), columns=["geom_left", "geom_right"], geometry="geom_left")

gdf_points = gpd.GeoDataFrame(sedona_df.rdd.collect(), columns=["geom_left", "geom_right"], geometry="geom_right")



folium_map = folium.Map(zoom_start=0.0001, tiles="CartoDB positron")

for _, r in gdf_points.iterrows():
    # Without simplifying the representation of each borough,
    # the map might not be displayed
    sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r["geom_right"]).simplify(tolerance=0.000001)

    geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j, style_function=lambda x: {"fillColor": "red"})
    geo_j.add_to(folium_map)


for _, r in gdf.iterrows():
    # Without simplifying the representation of each borough,
    # the map might not be displayed
    sim_geo = gpd.GeoSeries(r["geom_left"]).simplify(tolerance=0.000001)


    geo_j = sim_geo.to_json()
    geo_j = folium.GeoJson(data=geo_j, style_function=lambda x: {"fillColor": "yellow"})
    geo_j.add_to(folium_map)

folium_map.show_in_browser()
```

Output :

```
approximate count 3000
analyse is here True
Printng point list
[Geometry: Point userData: testattribute0   testattribute1  testattribute2, Geometry: Point userData: testattribute0    testattribute1  testattribute2, Geometry: Point userData: testattribute0    testattribute1  testattribute2, Geometry: Point userData: testattribute0    testattribute1  testattribute2, Geometry: Point userData: testattribute0    testattribute1  testattribute2]
GeoPandas Dataframe
                         geom           attr1           attr2           attr3
0  POINT (-88.33149 32.32414)  testattribute0  testattribute1  testattribute2
1  POINT (-88.17593 32.36076)  testattribute0  testattribute1  testattribute2
2  POINT (-88.38895 32.35707)  testattribute0  testattribute1  testattribute2
3  POINT (-88.22110 32.35078)  testattribute0  testattribute1  testattribute2
4  POINT (-88.32399 32.95067)  testattribute0  testattribute1  testattribute2
+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|attr1         |attr2         |attr3         |geom                        |
+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+
|testattribute0|testattribute1|testattribute2|POINT (-88.331492 32.324142)|
|testattribute0|testattribute1|testattribute2|POINT (-88.175933 32.360763)|
|testattribute0|testattribute1|testattribute2|POINT (-88.388954 32.357073)|
|testattribute0|testattribute1|testattribute2|POINT (-88.221102 32.35078) |
|testattribute0|testattribute1|testattribute2|POINT (-88.323995 32.950671)|
+--------------+--------------+--------------+----------------------------+
only showing top 5 rows

spatial partitioniing done value =  True
True
Result of the Join Query
[[Geometry: Polygon userData: , Geometry: Point userData: testattribute0    testattribute1  testattribute2], [Geometry: Polygon userData: , Geometry: Point userData: testattribute0    testattribute1  testattribute2]]
Schema of Sedona Dataframe
root
 |-- geom_left: geometry (nullable = false)
 |-- geom_right: geometry (nullable = false)

None
Values here
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|geom_left                                                                                                               |geom_right                  |
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
|POLYGON ((-88.40049 30.474455, -88.40049 30.692167, -88.006968 30.692167, -88.006968 30.474455, -88.40049 30.474455))   |POINT (-88.35457 30.634836) |
|POLYGON ((-88.40047 30.474213, -88.40047 30.691941, -88.007269 30.691941, -88.007269 30.474213, -88.40047 30.474213))   |POINT (-88.35457 30.634836) |
|POLYGON ((-88.403842 32.448773, -88.403842 32.737139, -88.099114 32.737139, -88.099114 32.448773, -88.403842 32.448773))|POINT (-88.347036 32.454904)|
|POLYGON ((-88.403842 32.448773, -88.403842 32.737139, -88.099114 32.737139, -88.099114 32.448773, -88.403842 32.448773))|POINT (-88.39203 32.507796) |
|POLYGON ((-88.403842 32.448773, -88.403842 32.737139, -88.099114 32.737139, -88.099114 32.448773, -88.403842 32.448773))|POINT (-88.349276 32.548266)|
|POLYGON ((-88.403842 32.448773, -88.403842 32.737139, -88.099114 32.737139, -88.099114 32.448773, -88.403842 32.448773))|POINT (-88.329313 32.618924)|
|POLYGON ((-88.403823 32.449032, -88.403823 32.737291, -88.09933 32.737291, -88.09933 32.449032, -88.403823 32.449032))  |POINT (-88.347036 32.454904)|
|POLYGON ((-88.403823 32.449032, -88.403823 32.737291, -88.09933 32.737291, -88.09933 32.449032, -88.403823 32.449032))  |POINT (-88.39203 32.507796) |
|POLYGON ((-88.403823 32.449032, -88.403823 32.737291, -88.09933 32.737291, -88.09933 32.449032, -88.403823 32.449032))  |POINT (-88.349276 32.548266)|
|POLYGON ((-88.403823 32.449032, -88.403823 32.737291, -88.09933 32.737291, -88.09933 32.449032, -88.403823 32.449032))  |POINT (-88.329313 32.618924)|
+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------------------+
only showing top 10 rows

Your map should have been opened in your browser automatically.
```

Following is the map opened in browser.

[image]