# Task stuck at "GET RESULT" from Join -> groupby in Spark (sedona)

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, geometry, apache-sedona

Working in spark 3.4.1, sedona, jupyter lab on a docker image

I'm trying to count the month with the most vessel points from ships from a large dataset with geographic info.
I have 2 dataframes, one with the points (Lon, lat, vessel name,date, etc.) and another one with some polygons (multipolygon, polygon name, + additional irrelevant info) from shape files.

The idea is to join both dataframes by the "ST_Contains" function and then group by the polygon name and count the number of points inside each one.

The points are in a csv file, which i read without problem, and same with the polygon file with the areas. The areas file only have 60 entries and the point file that i'm currently using has like 5M entries. I want to test with a small number of entries before i use the complete point dataset (5475M) but when i launch the join in spark with the query below, the task just stay at "GET RESULT" and eventually gives the error *TaskResultLost (result lost from block manager)*

```
most_point = sedona.sql(
"""
SELECT NAME, count(*) as cnt
FROM points p
inner join shape s on ST_Contains(s.geometry, ST_Point(p.LON, p.LAT))
group by NAME
  """)
most_point.show()
```

[executor status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yOWDC.png)
[Error in jupyter lab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRGuM.png)

I've tried adding more executors and memory, changing the "spark.shuffle.blockTransferService" to "nio" and  changing the query in more ways than i remember.

When i change the query so the area file is the "left" table it runs really slow but it gets the job done in about 2 hours by doing it on only 1 executor, but everytime i try to parallelize i get the taskResultLost Error.

I'm guessing that maybe some port is blocked but i don't have experience with spark: this is for a university class and the professor is nowhere to be seen.

Thank you!

Comment: I tried to do something similar recently. This worked locally without any issue. https://stackoverflow.com/a/77132181/3238085  Hope this helps. If not, I will delete this comment.

Comment: Thanks! I tried your solution but i'm getting the error once again. I think there's a problem with the infraestructure but the teacher assistant keeps telling me that i have a "too small dataframe without enough partitions" and "that's why is failing" :/

Comment: Check your paths. Are they pointing to correct files?