How can I check if a Point, which is in one dataframe, is in the Polygon which is located in the second dataframe in pyspark?
I have two files: one contains data on taxi trips in NYC and the other is a GeoJSON file with the borough boundaries of NYC. I need to create two new columns in the taxi trip dataframe. These columns should indicate the borough for the pickup location and the borough for the drop-off location for each trip.
I tried to use the following udf function:
def locate_borough(lon, lat, geometries):
point = Point(lon, lat)
for geo in geometries:
    polygon = Polygon(geo['geometry'])
    if point.within(polygon):
        return "borough_name"
return None

Polygon does not work since it receives a list.
Here is the code and schema of the borough dataframe:
boroughs_df = (spark.read.json("nyc-boroughs.geojson"))

boroughs_df = boroughs_df.drop("_corrupt_record").dropna()

def coord_to_poly(geometry):
    return shape(geometry.asDict()).wkt

udf_polygon = F.udf(coord_to_poly, StringType())
boroughs_df = boroughs_df.withColumn("polygon",udf_polygon(boroughs_df["geometry.coordinates"]))

# adding area and sorting
def area(geometry):
    return shape(geometry.asDict()).area
udf_area = F.udf(area, DoubleType())
boroughs_df = boroughs_df.withColumn("area", udf_area(boroughs_df["geometry"]))

#sorting
boroughs_df = boroughs_df.sort(F.desc("properties.boroughCode"), F.desc("area"))

#broadcasting
# boroughs_b_df = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(boroughs_df.collect())

boroughs_df.printSchema()
root
 |-- geometry: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- coordinates: array (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |-- element: array (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |    |    |-- element: double (containsNull = true)
 |    |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- id: long (nullable = true)
 |-- properties: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- @id: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- borough: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- boroughCode: long (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- polygon: string (nullable = true)
 |-- area: double (nullable = true)

Here is the the code and schema for the taxi-ride dataframe:
taxi_df = (spark.read
            .option("header", "true")
            .option("inferSchema", "true")
             .csv("sample.csv")
            )
taxi_df.printSchema()
    root
 |-- medallion: string (nullable = true)
 |-- hack_license: string (nullable = true)
 |-- vendor_id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- rate_code: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- store_and_fwd_flag: string (nullable = true)
 |-- pickup_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- dropoff_datetime: timestamp (nullable = true)
 |-- passenger_count: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- trip_time_in_secs: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- trip_distance: double (nullable = true)
 |-- pickup_longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- pickup_latitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dropoff_longitude: double (nullable = true)
 |-- dropoff_latitude: double (nullable = true)

I want to make so that each row in the taxi dataframe would have its own borough value,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/77132181/3238085  This answer could be helpful.

Thank you, but it didn't help because I got a new error using that code.

Can you post sample input and output?
